# jQuery ajax returns images data, but other JS code no longer visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is the scaled down example of how the .item click function is no longer visible after ajax returns data (right data)
    nothing

```
<div class='curve4' id='leftMenuPanel'>
   <li>clicker</li>
</div>

                <script>
$('.item').click(function() {
    console.log('yes clicked');
});

        $(document).find("div.curve4 li").on("click", function(e){

                e.preventDefault();

                var selection = "nevada"; //$(this).find("a").first().attr("href").split("=")[1];
                console.log("selection: "+selection);

                var that = $(this);

                $.ajax({
                        url:"/images-ajax.php",
                        cache:false,
                        data:"s="+selection,
                        method:"post",
                        success:function(html){
                                $(".masonryImg").html(html);
                                $("div.curve4 li").removeClass("selected");
                                that.addClass("selected");
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                console.log(xhr.status);
                                console.log(thrownError);
                          }
                });

        });
        </script>
```

the output returned is correctly put into the div, but when clicking on the new images returned from ajax, the javascript 3 lines just above the ajax call no longer work.

this is what ajax returns:

```
<img class='item' data-src='/images/500/2014-01-04-lajolla-seal-5d3_8809.jpg' width='300' src='/images/500/2014-01-04-lajolla-seal-5d3_8809.jpg'>
<img class='item' data-src='/images/500/2014-01-04-lajolla-sunset-1x_22133.jpg' width='300' src='/images/500/2014-01-04-lajolla-sunset-1x_22133.jpg'>
<img class='item' data-src='/images/500/2014-01-04-lajolla-cave-5d3_8545.jpg' width='300' src='/images/500/2014-01-04-lajolla-cave-5d3_8545.jpg'>
```

One topic is that the original data has only data-src parts, not src (the above ajax returns both). but if the ajax above does not have the src parts and only has data-src, the images don't show.

prior to the ajax call, the data written on screen is:

```
document.write('<img class="item" data-src="'
                           + imagesLocation + images[currentImage] + ".jpg"
                           +'" width="300">');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that jQuery attaches the events once but when you overwrite the html, so the events are lost. Instead, use jquery's `on`:

```
$(".masonryImg").on("click", ".item", function() {
    console.log("Clicked!");
});
```